# Tolven source to Eclipse project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, open-source

I have tolven(an open source PHR and CHR system) source code and I found it is a package of several plugins. The wiki at tolven provides installation of tolven in windows/linux systems but I want to do more like a developer. So I want this tolven source in developing mode like imported to an IDE mainly Eclipse. There is no guide about how to do this in the wiki. Can any one suggest how to do this?

tolven source is available at : http://sourceforge.net/projects/tolven/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure of your Eclipse version. In 4.2, Select **Window>Open Perspective>Other...** and then **CVS Repository Exploring**. In the "CVS Repositories View", right click and select **New>Repository Location...**.

- Connection Type: pserver
- User: anonymous
- Host: tolven.cvs.sourceforge.net
- Repository Path: /cvsroot/tolven
- Use default port

Click on **OK**. You should see something like this:
[image: Eclipse CVS Repositories View]

You're going to want this to be an Eclipse Java Project. So create a Java project with separate source and binary folders. In the "CVS Repositories View", right click on the stuff you want to edit in Eclipse and select **Check Out As...**. Select **...into an existing project**, then **Next>**. Now select the source folder of the Java project you just created. and **Finish**.

You're probably going to want to move the non-Java files, but this gets the Java source in the right place.